# Дополнить метку flask-wtf

Tags: обсуждение, метки, описание-метки

Сегодня наткнулся на вопрос с меткой [flask-wtf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-wtf). Стало любопытно, вдруг эта метка имеет какое-то значимое обоснование. Но увидел лишь, что создана она в этом году, по ней задано 6 вопросов и у неё нет описания.

Трактовка метки, как я понимаю, базируется на "это фласк, и я не понимаю, что тут не так", в связи с чем хотелось бы выдвинуть на обсуждение удаление метки [flask-wtf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-wtf), как ненужной в свете существования метки [flask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask).

P.s. если вдруг метка действительно имеет смысл, и значение этой метки понято мной неправильно, этой метке следует добавить валидное описание.

---

UPD: изучил вопрос, метка имеет место быть, но всё ещё остаётся вопрос о необходимости валидного описания для метки

Comment: Не-не, flask-wtf это такой конкретный инструмент для интеграции библиотеки WTForms с фласком. И вопрос не про WTForms кажется всего один

Comment: @andreymal я уже разобрался в этом вопросе, и само тело вопроса обновил. Проблема отсутствия описания всё ещё актуальна